# Using the emacs bindings in pycharm in OS X Lion

Tags: python, osx-lion, pycharm

I am trying to use the emacs keybindings in Pycharm 1.5 in OS X 10.7. They all work except that <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> inserts a beta symbol rather than moving back a word. It's puzzling since <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> does correctly move forward a word. 
Also, I was wondering if Pycharm has support for moving between matching parentheses or brackets, like Control-Meta-F in emacs. I didn't see an option for this in the Pycharm keybindings preference pane. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution on the [JetBrains forum.](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5300902#5300902) The forum post includes a keymap as an attachment that globally disables the alt keys from generating symbols.

Quoting the forum, 
"So, after some digging around, I figured that this option key maps to these relatively unused symbols that are take precedence in the operating system. Using http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele (Ukelele), I was able to generate an optimized Emacs keyboard layout. You should take this and put it in your /Library/Keyboard Layouts/ folder.

Reboot, and switch to use this keyboard layout on the Mac OSX toolbar and the option key will be free for hotkeying in PyCharm. I'll write up a blog post about this later.

Hope this helps."

Comment: I have the same experience as the original poster, but I don't see why pycharm can't override these silly system defaults.  Emacs can---and that is really, really old code.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>esc</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> works for me, but <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> doesn't. It's right there in the emacs keymap, so it's strange at first, but I think the problem is that <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>  is mapped to a character (∫ rather than ß in my case) so PyCharm doesn't see it as a key-modifier pair, just a single character.

Switching to a different international keyboard map will change which combinations work and which don't. I'd suggest sending a bug report to PyCharm as it's something they can fix, or alternatively you'll have to hack your keyboard mapping somehow.

To answer your other question, I don't think that there's a way to go to matching parenthesis, or at least I've never found one.